# Unable to submit Sitecore Form after adding Google Recaptcha V3

Tags: sitecore-forms

I followed the below post to create a custom field for Recaptcha in Sitecore forms-
https://dev.to/chandra_kodi/sitecore-google-recaptcha-v3-5d18

Faced multiple issues, resolved them, and now I am stuck in the final issue. I am getting an error in console

[image]

I tried to add input as `GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes` eg below:-

```
<input id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClass" type="hidden" value="" @Html.GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(m => Model.Value) />
```

I did check this one too - [Sitecore Forms on Submit: Cannot read property 'unobtrusive' of undefined](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/sitecore-forms-on-submit-cannot-read-property-unobtrusive-of-undefined)

Please suggest.

Comment: Is that any help? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/sitecore-forms-on-submit-cannot-read-property-unobtrusive-of-undefined